# Getting info from two database tables with one URL

Tags: php

I have a site which works well by using URL's to get data from a database, i.e.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/product.php?cat=photo&att=latestphotos
```

...brings up the latest photos and

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/product.php?cat=photo&att=photocompilations
```

...brings up photo compilations.

What I would like to do is have one URL that will bring up a combined results from the two above, both latest photos AND compilations.

Is this possible?

Comment: Of course.  What have you tried?

Comment: You could try, http://www.mywebsite.com/product.php?cat=photo&att=latestphotos+photocompilations+somemagicsauce

Answer (score 1):

You can ofcourse add up multiple get variables in the url like

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/product.php?cat=photo&att=latestphotos&att2=photocompilations
```

Or add an array like

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/product.php?cat=photo&att=latestphotos+photocompilations
```

Then use respective database to fetch the results using `mysqli_query()`

Comment: Would be an array if you exploded the get variable att otherwise its just a string with a plus.

Comment: &att[]=latestphotos&att[]=photocompilations  on the other hand, would be.